# Is a majority vote from two classifiers trained on m data each better than one classifier trained on 2m data?

Tags: machine-learning, probability

How does the performance of ensemble classifiers compare to a single classifier in the PAC learning framework? Specifically, consider $2m$ i.i.d samples $(x, y) \in \mathcal{X} \times \{-1, 1\}$ from a distribution  $\mathcal{D}$, which is a binary classification task. Imagine one learner divides the data into two equal-sized subsets, $S_1$ and $S_2$, and trains two classifiers, $h_1$ and $h_2$. This learner's final prediction is $h_3 = \text{sign}\left(\frac{h_1 + h_2}{2}\right)$. How does this approach's sample complexity and generalization error compare to directly training a single classifier on all $2m$ data points? How can one mathematically argue for or against this method within the PAC framework?

It might be wrong because we don't normally train a classifier in that way, however, it might be right since the majority vote helps learning. ([The Optimal Sample Complexity of PAC Learning](https://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume17/15-389/15-389.pdf) uses a majority vote classifier)